# How can I print out scanned in structure to file properly? (C)

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am trying to read from *2 files (f1.txt and f2.txt)* using `structures` and `print` them out to the *third file (f3.txt)*, but I seem to be getting some errors. Issues did not occur before I tried printing out the values to the file `(fprintf command)`, and I cant seem to find a way to fix it..

This is for a homework assignment, but since I've been struggling to fix this issue for months now (yes, I'm pretty bad), I thought maybe anyone here knows how I can fix this.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_NIME_PIKKUS 100
#define MAX_AINE_PIKKUS 100
#define MAX_KOOD 10
#define MAX_HINNE 5

#define DEBUG 0

    int n;
    int m;

struct Tudeng{
    char Nimi[MAX_NIME_PIKKUS];
    char Kood[MAX_KOOD];
};
struct Tudeng *pTudeng;

struct Aine{
    char Nimetus[MAX_AINE_PIKKUS];
    char aineKood[MAX_KOOD];
};
struct Aine *pAine;

struct Tud{
    char Tudengikood[MAX_KOOD];
    int Hinne[MAX_HINNE];
};
struct Tud *pTud;

char f1[] = "f1.txt";
char f2[] = "f2.txt";
char f3[] = "f3.txt";
FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp3;

int sisendf1_kontroll();
int sisendf2_kontroll();
void tekita_failid();
void andmed_failidesse(char Tudeng1, char Tudeng2, char Aine1, char Aine2, char Tud1, int Tud2);

int main(void){
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    n = sisendf1_kontroll();
    printf("Failist %s loeti %d tudengi andmed.\n", f1, n);
    m = sisendf2_kontroll();
    printf("Failist %s loeti %d aine andmed.\n", f2, m);
    fp1 = fopen(f1,"r");
    fp2 = fopen(f2, "r");
    int i = 0;

    a = sizeof(struct Tudeng);
    b = sizeof(struct Aine);
    c = sizeof(struct Tud);

    pTudeng = malloc(a * n);
    pAine = malloc(b * m);
    pTud = malloc(c * m);

    if(DEBUG)printf("Struktuuri Tudeng baidi aadress on %p, ühe kirje andmeteks eraldati mälu %d baiti, mälu eraldati massiivile kokku %d baiti \n", pTudeng, a, a * n);
    if(DEBUG)printf("Struktuuri Aine baidi aadress on %p, ühe kirje andmeteks eraldati mälu %d baiti, mälu eraldati massiivile kokku %d baiti \n", pAine, b, b * m);
    if(DEBUG)printf("Struktuuri Tud baidi aadress on %p, ühe kirje andmeteks eraldati mälu %d baiti, mälu eraldati massiivile kokku %d baiti \n", pTud, c, c * m);
    int loopiks;

while(loopiks == 0){
    while(!feof(fp1)){
        fscanf(fp1,"%s",(pTudeng+i)->Nimi);
        fscanf(fp1,"%s",(pTudeng+i)->Kood);
        i++;
    }

    while(!feof(fp2)){
        fscanf(fp2,"%s",(pAine+i)->Nimetus);
        fscanf(fp2,"%s",(pAine+i)->aineKood);
        fscanf(fp2,"%s",(pTud+i)->Tudengikood);
        fscanf(fp2,"%d",(pTud+i)->Hinne);
        i++;
    }
    loopiks = 1;
    tekita_failid();
    andmed_failidesse((pTudeng+i->Nimi), (pTudeng+i)->Kood, (pAine+i)->Nimetus, (pAine+i)->aineKood, (pTud+i)->Tudengikood, (pTud+i)->Hinne);

    free(pTudeng);
    free(pAine);
    free(pTud);
}

    //fprintf(fp3, "%s %s\n",(pTudeng+i)->Nimi,(pTudeng+i)->Kood);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;    
}

int sisendf1_kontroll(void){
    char rida[122];
    int n = 0, p;
    fp1 = fopen(f1,"r");

    if(fp1 == NULL){
        printf("Sisendfaili %s avamine ebaonnestus!", f1);
        exit(1);
    }else{
        while(!feof(fp1)){
            fgets(rida, 122, fp1);
            p = strlen(rida);
            if (p > 1) n++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return n;
}

int sisendf2_kontroll(void){
    char rida2[122];
    int m = 0, o;
    fp2 = fopen(f2,"r");

    if(fp2==NULL){
        printf("Sisendfaili %s avamine ebaonnestus!", f2);
        exit(1);
    }else{
        while(!feof(fp2)){
            fgets(rida2, 122, fp2);
            o = strlen(rida2);
            if (o > 1) m++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp2);
    return m;
}

void tekita_failid(){
    fp3 = fopen(f3, "w");
    fclose(fp3);
    return;
}

void andmed_failidesse(char Tudeng1, char Tudeng2, char Aine1, char Aine2, char Tud1, int Tud2){
    fp3 = fopen(f3, "a");
    int i;
    int j;
    while(i < n && j < m){
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            fprintf(fp3, "%s %s ",(pTudeng+i)->Nimi,(pTudeng+i)->Kood);
        }
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
            fprintf(fp3, "%s %s %s %d \n",(pAine+i)->Nimetus,(pAine+i)->aineKood, (pTud+i)->Tudengikood, (pTud+i)->Hinne);
    }
}
        return;
}
```

I expected the program to output the information from *f1.txt and f2.txt* to *f3.txt,* but currently compiler tells me that I cannot do that, since I'm using `* int` in last function, but it says that regular int is required.

Comment: First of all, please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Secondly please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also please don't use global variables. If multiple functions need to use them, then pass them around as arguments instead. Also please read [Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: Failing to check the return of EVERY `fscanf` invites *Undefined Behavior*. Pay careful attention to the comment by @Someprogrammerdude above.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is right: 
`andmed_failidesse` expects an `int` as last parameter and you're passing `Hinne` which is an array of `int`, aka `int*`.

As `Tud2` is not used anyway in your current code you can remove it from function signature or rework your function to use it.
Your compiler should also warn you that you have other unused parameters in your function.

It is obviously a work in progress: take a break, re-read your C courses and try to figure out what your function is supposed to do, and which parameters it needs.